# Can I get line number or stack trace from gtkmm and glibmm runtime diagnostic messages?

Tags: glib

I'm writing a toy program using gtkmm and glibmm, which are C++ bindings for GTK and Glib. I'm getting some runtime diagnostic messages. They look like this:

```
(process:2933): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:19:16.920: g_object_set_qdata_full: assertion 'quark > 0' failed
```

The heading format already include pid and filename most of the time. However, I'd also like to see some line numbers of the corresponding source. Is it possible?

Please don't read this into a form of X-Y question, or don't fix on a particular message. Since I periodically run into - and eventually manage to mend - many of them.

Answer (score 1):

As is said in [*Running GLib Applications*](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/running.html), setting env G_DEBUG to include "fatal-warnings" or "fatal-criticals" will let the program raise a signal SIGTRAP whenever such a diagnostic is encountered. Catching this signal in a debugger may help to look into the stack, etc.

Example usage:

```
# to dump stack upon first critical diagnostic and quit
G_DEBUG=fatal-criticals gdb -batch -ex "run" -ex "i stack" ./a.out

# or upon first and second critical and or warning diagnostic whichever comes earlier
G_DEBUG=fatal-warnings gdb -batch -ex "run" -ex "i stack" -ex "cont" -ex "i stack" ./a.out
```

Comment: This is particularly useful, because getting line numbers for those warning messages wouldn’t actually help you — the line numbers would always point inside GLib code, rather than the buggy code which called `g_object_set_qdata_full()`. It’s not technically possible to print the line number of the original call without turning all GLib functions into macro wrappers which pass `__LINE__` through to the actual GLib function. That’s infeasible.